# I can't go back the Panel with the original options to create an object

Tags: modeling, panel

I'm not sure how to explain my question so I have some Images.

When I first create the object the panel Sapling: Add Tree shows up but if i then go and do something else the panel disappears.

[image]
[image]

I cant seem to find a way to bring it back does anyone know how

Thanks

Comment: I had a look at the possible duplicate of but it did not help

Comment: You're right it is not possible to get the panel back after object creation is completed.

Comment: Can't get the panel back, but it is possible to retrieve the previously run operator properties from the window_manager.operators collection (via py console or script), or copy from the info window and paste into py console to create same tree.  Would need to insert 'INVOKE_DEFAULT` eg `bpy.ops.curve.tree_add('INVOKE_DEFAULT', do_update=True, ...)` .  Once the file is closed these too will be lost.  A lot of operators save your last settings, sapling is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Once the original object has been created, and has gone through some kind of transformation, **there is no way to get the original creation parameters panel back**

Comment: Have a look at my comment on Q, I believe you can get the parameters back, not the panel.

Comment: @batFINGER please do write an answer with that info.