# Sapling tree add on, can edit the trees after doing something else?

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode, sapling-addon

I'm working with the blender-version v2.77 and I'm making one of my first trees with the sapling tree add on. Does anyone of you know if you still can edit the trees after doing something else?
So for example you made the tree, and than modeled something else. Can you still edit the tree than (for me the leafs)?

Comment: No you can't go back and set the parameters .

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70297/i-cant-go-back-the-panel-with-the-original-options-to-create-an-object/70305#70305