# Sapling addon panel back

Tags: sapling-addon

When I select another object and transform it the **Sapling tree generator** panel is gone. I can't get it back when I **reselect** the tree. Is it possible at all to have the panel back?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70297/i-cant-go-back-the-panel-with-the-original-options-to-create-an-object